# Is there a music player that supports play counts and smart playlists?

Tags: applications, sync, media-player

I'm looking for a music player for Android that supports smart playlists and play count metadata like the iPod and iTunes.  Ideally I'd like something that:

- Keeps track of statistics like last played, play count, last skipped, etc.
- Allows rating of songs from Android.
- Supports smart playlists that are live updating (for example, if I have a smart playlist to match all songs I haven't played in a month, and I play a song from it, the played song drops off the playlist **without having to sync back with my PC** since it no longer matches that criteria).
- Is supported by a desktop PC media management application such that these statistics are synchronized back to the PC.  (I'm open to switching, so as long as it's supported by a stable, relatively featured desktop app, I don't care which).

I've tried the stock music player, which doesn't support any of these (to my knowledge), and doubleTwist, which supports ratings but doesn't support smart playlists or play counts yet.

Comment: I'm right there with you on this. I've had a hard enough time finding a Windows application that supports these features, let alone a companion on Android. Currently using Songbird on Windows and doubleTwist on Android but these leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Scrobbling (or simply a file with a list of played songs) would be nice too.  I agree with all the other points.

Answer (score 7):

iSyncr does this. They also do wireless sync. [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5655180/isyncr-syncs-your-android-device-with-itunes-over-usb-or-wi+fi)

Unfortunately (for me at least) it uses iTunes and I hate iTunes, but it does work. I think I hated iTunes so much I bought an Android to avoid it, but now have to use it anyway because of the smart playlists. It is the only thing I've found that keeps smart playlists, playcounts, and ratings updated. Everything you said you wanted. Plus you already use iTunes and seem to not hate it.

I think iSyncr could work for you. :)

You should be able to use the stock music player, MixZing, or a half dozen other popular other android players in combination with the sync app which pushes playcounts and ratings to iTunes.

Comment: This looks promising; I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: iTunes is a no-go, for me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into it much, but perhaps you should check out Winamp.  They have an android player in beta now that supports wireless and USB synchronization to a PC that is also running Winamp.

The App is currently not available on PlayStore. You can download the apk from the official Winamp forums and download the app under the Android category,

[Download WinAmp](http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=2984799&postcount=2) Page

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned [PlayerPro Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro) - which does exactly what you need.

Here's the related PlayStore description,

> Music stats and SMART PLAYLISTS: Recently added, Top rated, Most
>   played, Recently played, Least played. Build additional custom
>   playlists using the SMART PLAYLIST EDITOR and the many different
>   criteria it offers: album, artist, genre, title, play/skip count, last
>   played/added, rating, is a podcast, duration, year, file path etc. All
>   smart playlists are AUTO-UPDATED.

There's also a 10-day trial version of this app available on PlayStore, if you want to try out the features,

[PlayerPro Music Player Trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerprotrial).

***Note:*** The Pro version is standalone. Please uninstall the trial version after purchase.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the app? Searching for "Player Pro" returning [PlayerPro Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro) which has 10-day free trial version, but last updated on Dec 2014.

Comment: Hi, yes, that is the player, and I got the last update date from the "What's New" section. I see now that they released a new version today! I'm very excited!!!

Answer (score 0):

[MixZing Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixzing.basic), I believe, does both. At the very least, it supports "semi-smart" playlists generated according to your rating tracks.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly recommended app for this is [DoubleTwist](http://www.appbrain.com/app/music-%28doubletwist-music%29/com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer). Along with the desktop app it will let you import any iTunes playlists, counts, etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will only say that the Winamp player has 'Rating' from android in their 'to-do' list.  I'm hopeful for this.

I will second the op's criteria for what I'm looking for in Android.  At this point, I think Winamp has the potential for really being the iPod/iTunes combo killer.  To make all of the above happen somewhat flawlessly, there needs to be a true "library" type sync, and not this reliance on the last.fm scrobbling.  If it can keep a small version of a library on the phone, and use THAT to sync up to the main computer, it could be AMAZING.

Answer (score -3):

Rocket Player Pro does that exactly.